# Getting mask of numpy array according to vector-type elements

Tags: python, numpy, mask

We can find indices of a scalar in numpy array like below:

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array([1,2,3])
mask = (array == 2) #mask is now [False,True,False]
```

When element is a vector:

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array([[1,2],[1,4],[5,6]])
mask = (array == [1,4]) #mask is now [[True,False],[True,True],[False,False]]
```

I actually want to generate a similar mask like in the first code snippet in the second example.

```
mask = [False,True,False]
```

Is this possible in numpy library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the comparison is element-wise, you need to reduce it using `all` on the first axis:

```
(array == [1, 4]).all(axis=1)
Out: array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint @ayhan